# Filtrar un array para sacar repetidos pero con datos diferentes PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, array

Tengo el resultado de una consulta MYSQL

```
[
  {
    "placa": "VVV-WWW",
    "nombreCond": "HELBERT PATO",
    "fecha_servicio": "2020-09-01 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "placa": "VVV-WWW",
    "nombreCond": "JUAN RAMIRO",
    "fecha_servicio": "2020-09-02 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "placa": "VVV-WWW",
    "nombreCond": "JUAN RAMIRO",
    "fecha_servicio": "2020-09-03 00:00:00"
  }
]
```

Lo que quiero hacer es filtrar para que me bote el siguiente resultado porque algunos datos son repetidos como placa y nombre de conductor

```
[
    {
        "placa" : "VVV-WWW",
        "cond_fech" : [
            {
                "conductor" : "HELBERT PATO",
                "fechas" : {
                    "0" : "2020-09-01 00:00:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "conductor" : "JUAN RAMIRO",
                "fechas" : {
                    "0" : "2020-09-02 00:00:00",
                    "1" : "2020-09-03 00:00:00"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Intente lo siguiente, pero me sigue botando datos repetidos (intente usar el array_push para crear un nuevo array donde estaran las placas e ir iterando hasta dividirlo como el resultado que quiero)

```
$arr_veh = array();
$arr_serv = array();
foreach ($cond_serv as $veh) {
    array_push($arr_veh,$veh->placa);
    $arr_serv[$veh->placa] = ["cond_serv"=>[]];
}
$arr_veh = array_unique($arr_veh);
foreach ($arr_veh as $cont => $veh_serv) {
    foreach ($cond_serv as $cont => $serv) {
        if ( $serv->placa == $veh_serv )
        {
            array_push($arr_serv[$veh_serv]["cond_serv"],["conductor"=>$serv->nombreCond,"fechas"=>$serv->fecha_servicio]);
        }
    }
}
return $arr_serv;
```

Resultado del codigo anterior, como ven sigue habiendo datos repetidos y ademas creo que el codigo que hize es un desastre

```
{
  "VVV-WWW": {
    "cond_serv": [
      {
        "conductor": "HELBERT PATO",
        "fechas": "2020-09-01 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "conductor": "JUAN RAMIRO",
        "fechas": "2020-09-02 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "conductor": "JUAN RAMIRO",
        "fechas": "2020-09-03 00:00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes al realizar las iteraciones es que no está definido el modelo de agrupación de la información al momento de organizarla. Interpretando la propuesta de salida que deseas quieres un array de varios niveles de profundidad con el siguiente formato:

```
<?php
$modelo_de_salida = [
    'placa_1' => [
        'cond_serv' => [
            [
                'conductor' => 'nombre_conductor_1',
                'fechas' => [
                    'fecha_1', 'fecha_2', ..., 'fecha_n'
                ]
            ],
            [
                'conductor' => 'nombre_conductor_2',
                'fechas' => [
                    'fecha_1', 'fecha_2', ..., 'fecha_n'
                ]
            ],

        ],
        'otros_datos', // si no piensas alojar más datos por placa 'cond_serv' sobra
    ],
    // otras placas
];
```

Con el modelo de salida definido es más fácil saber qué se debe lograr en cada iteración. En lo personal creo que la clave 'cond_serv' plantea un nivel de anidación adicional que no sería necesario si no piensas anidar atributos o valores adicionales bajo cada placa (rutas, clientes, recaudo, etc.)

Como en la información que ofreces indicas que los conductores pueden repetirse, voy a suponer que **un mismo conductor puede ser asociado con varias placas** y que a su vez para su eventual aparición, ligado a cada placa, puede tener varias fechas.
Esto hace que tenga que hacer un *recorrido de preparación* para separar la información y volverla manejable y luego un ciclo de *formateo de salida* para entregarla como la necesitas. (Otras personas pueden sugerir mejores mecanismos, pero tristemente a mi no se me ocurre algo mejor):

**Ciclo de preparación de la información**

```
<?php
// Declaro unas variables intermedias que voy a usar para separar y organizar los valores
// 1. Array para recoger las placas y asociarles los conductores
// tendrá la forma: [placa_1 => [conductor_1, conductor_2, ...], ...] 
$placa_conductores = [];
// 2. Array para recoger fechas ligadas a cada dupla (placa, conductor)
// tendrá la forma [..., placa_i_conductor_j => [fecha_1, ...], ...]
$placa_conductor_fechas = [];

// Ciclo de preparación de la información (uso tu variable de entrada)
foreach ($cond_serv as $veh) {
    // creo una clave temporal placa_conductor para recoger la fecha
    $clavePlacaCond = $veh->placa . '_' . $veh->nombreCond; // se usará más abajo
    // Verifico si la placa ya fue recogida, en caso de que no lo haya sido
    // se agrega creando el sub_array que recoge sus conductores
    if(!isset($placa_conductores[$veh->placa])){
        $placa_conductores[$veh->placa] = [];
    }
    // Si el conductor no ha sido incluido se agrega
    if(!in_array($veh->nombreCond, $placa_conductores[$veh->placa])){
        $placa_conductores[$veh->placa][] = $veh->nombreCond;
        // y se agrega al array para recoger fechas asociadas al par conductor placa
        $placa_conductor_fechas[$clavePlacaCond] = [];
    }
    // agrego la fecha al array de recoleccion de fechas
    $placa_conductor_fechas[$clavePlacaCond][] = $veh->fecha_servicio;
}
```

Finalmente con la información preparada se puede organizar para que sea entregada con el formato deseado.

**Ciclo de formateo de salida**

```
<?php
// Declaro el array en que se entregará la salida
$salida = [];
// ejecuto el ciclo de paso de información
foreach($placa_conductores as $placa => $conductores){
    // No necesito validaciones ya que por construcción las placas son únicas
    $salida[$placa] = [ "cond_serv" => [] ];
    // si no se necesita "cond_serv" puede hacerse
    // $salida[$placa] = [];
    foreach($conductores as $conductor){
        // recreo la clave usada para recoger fechas 
        $clavePlacaCond = $placa . '_' . $conductor;
        // Agrego los datos al array de salida en la posición deseada
        $salida[$placa]["cond_serv"][] = [
            'conductor' => $conductor,
            'fechas' => $placa_conductor_fechas[$clavePlacaCond]
        ];
        // si no se va a usar la anidación bajo "cond_serv" descomentar el bloque siguiente
        /* $salida[$placa][] = [
            'conductor' => $conductor,
            'fechas' => $placa_conductor_fechas[$clavePlacaCond]
        ]; // */
    }
    // no hace falta interpolar validaciones pues por construcción la
    // unicidad de las claves está asegurada
}
// El resultado deseado se encuentra en $salida
// puedes verlo haciendo
echo $salida;
// o
var_dump($salida);
// para usarlo en otros contextos puedes pasarlo a json
```

**referencias**
Para manejo de funciones de arrays debes consultar: [Funciones de arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.array.php)

Comment: Gracias, estaba investigando mas ese tema de los arrays, el array_reduce me parecio interesante, y el tema de las agrupaciones mmm tengo mucho que aprender todavia. No me gusta copiar siempre el codigo de otros porque siento que no hice nada para obtener lo que quiero, lo tomare como referencia y si es posible lo mejorare, gracias denuevo por todo :D

Comment: @JuanRivera Con seguridad lo vas a mejorar. Para mi uso personal yo hice una clase que ofrece métodos para todo lo que necesito y desearía hacer con arrays multinivel. Te sugiero que te propongas algo similar como camino de aprendizaje

Comment: una consulta mas, el "cond_serv", lo puse para agregar mas datos, como el id u otras cosas, si quiero agregarle eso al resultado final. Como se haria?
Me salio agregando otro foreach del "cond_serv" y validando la placa, pero no se si es correcto

Comment: Necesitas la placa como mecanismo de control de los subarrays así: supongamos que a la placa GFN-816 deseas asignarle un valor de facturación total haces: `$salida['GFN-816']['facturo'] = 4356400;` ese dato va a quedar al lado de "cond_serv" bajo la misma placa.

Comment: @JuanRivera Ya te respondí a la pregunta adicional

Comment: vale, muchas gracias! @quevedo

Comment: Investigando la funcion array_reduce, logre reducirlo a 12 lineas de codigo @quevedo, agrego mi respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Para hacer lo que queria, tome el modelo de agrupacion que me dijo @quevedo, pero lo modifique un poco para los conductores por ID

```
$modelo_de_salida = [
    'placa_1' => [
        'cond_serv' => [
            'idConductor' => [
                
                'conductor' => 'nombre_conductor_1',
                'fechas' => [
                    'fecha_1', 'fecha_2', ..., 'fecha_n'
                ]
            ],
            'idConductor' =>[
                'conductor' => 'nombre_conductor_2',
                'fechas' => [
                    'fecha_1', 'fecha_2', ..., 'fecha_n'
                ]
            ],

        ],
        'otros_datos', // si no piensas alojar más datos por placa 'cond_serv' sobra
    ],
    // otras placas
];
```

Despues investigue y entre el [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-reduce.php) donde podremos hacer lo siguiente:

```
//Se invoca la funcion "array_reduce" definiendo directamente el callback
//que será iterado en los parámetros que se le pasan. Y, en su signatura 
//se establece la variable de acumulación "accumulator" e "item" que 
//será usada por "array_reduce" para pasarlos elementos del array a reducir
// en las iteraciones.

// "$accomulator": Sera un array vacío donde llenaremos los datos.
// array_reduce lo usa para pasar al callback el valor devuelto por el mismo
// en la iteración inmediatamente anterior.
// Y lo entrega al terminar "el recorrido" como resultado.
// "$item": Nos servira para sacar los valores del array.

$salida =  array_reduce($cond_serv , function($accumulator, $item){
    // Este index sera la ID principal ('placa_1')
    $index = $item->placa_veh;
    
    // Aqui estamos poniendo una condicion para ir agregando todas las "placas"('placa_1')
    if (!isset($accumulator[$index])) {
       // Despues, dentro de la placa colocamos la variable "cond_fech" con un array vacio,
       // Saldria asi: 'placa_1' => [ 'cond_serv' => [] ]
       $accumulator[$index] = [ "cond_serv" => [] ];
    }
    // Despues dentro de 'cond_serv', ponemos el ID de los conductores para que se agrupen con ello y dentro
    // Asignamos la variable 'conductor' donde ira el nombre del conductor
    // Saldria asi: 'placa_1' => [ 'cond_serv' => [ 'idConductor' => [ 'conductor' => 'nombre_conductor_1'] ]
    $accumulator[$index]["cond_serv"][$item->idConductor]['conductor'] = $item->nombreCond;
    // Luego ponemos otra variable 'fechas' con un array vacio '[]' donde iran las fechas que pertenece a cada conductor
    // Saldria asi: 'placa_1' => [ 'cond_serv' => [ 'idConductor' => [ 'conductor' => 'nombre_conductor_1', 'fechas' => [ 'fecha_1', 'fecha_2', ..., 'fecha_n' ] ] ] ]
    $accumulator[$index]["cond_serv"][$item->idConductor]['fechas'][] = [
        'fecha_servicio' => $item->fecha_servicio
    ];
    
    // Por ultimo retornamos nuestro $accomulator que devuelve el array de la primera 'placa_1'
    return $accumulator;
 }, []);
```

Comment: Hola, Juan. Aunque algunos puedan saber lo que hace el código, intenta siempre explicarlo para que tanto la persona que hace la pregunta como otras personas que puedan tener la misma duda o el mismo problema puedan saber lo que hace el código. Saludos.

Comment: Excelente mejora Juan!! No obstante, hace falta que documentes un poco como te dice @Adrián.

Comment: Hola @quevedo ya puse la explicación, no soy bueno haciéndolo, si aun no es entendible podrías mejorarlo?

Comment: Hola. Agregué algunos comentarios al mecanismo de definición en línea del callback. Están, en cola, pendientes de aprobación. ¡Tu explicación es buena!